# Хранение и выборка параметров фильтрации в БД

Tags: postgresql, структуры-данных

**Задача:** имеется таблица продуктов

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    id UUID NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    shop VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Нужно определить - *как хранить фильтры к этим продуктам в БД с учетом следующего:*

*Первое условие* - фильтры бывают следующие:

1. фильтр продуктов по полю name - допускаются только те продукты, наименования которых встречаются в заданном массиве строк.
2. фильтр продуктов по полю shop - допускаются только те продукты, магазины которых встречаются в заданном массиве строк.
3. фильтры в пунктах 1 и 2 можно комбинировать с применением булевых операций И, ИЛИ, НЕ. Например:
   ['name a','name b'] И НЕ ['shop c'] ИЛИ НЕ(['name 1'] И ['shop 2', 'shop z'])

*Второе условие* - иногда для фильтров нужно будет выполнять такой запрос:
Задается массив с наименованиями продуктов. Нужно найти все фильтры, которым соответствует хотя бы один продукт, наименование которого встречается в заданном массиве.

**Что не получается:** т.к. фильтры могут представлять собой сложное логическое выражение, то я решил представить их в виде дерева - где узлами являются логические операции, а листьями фильтры типов 1 и 2. Я посчитал, что для хранения иерархической структуры хорошо подойдет тип JSONB. Собственно с сохранением фильтров у меня проблем не возникло. Однако с таким подходом я не могу понять, как построить описанный в задаче запрос.

Comment: А зачем ИЛИ ? Вы много видели пользователей которые вообще задают что то сложное в поиске ? По моему И вполне достаточно при наличии массивов и НЕ. Кому может понадобится искать "Булка" ИЛИ магазин "Номер 2" ? Если убрать возможность ИЛИ, то все становиться очень просто, видим массив - значит IN или набор OR его заменяющий. если не массив - значит одиночное значение. Добавить НЕ в конструкции то же не проблема, а дальше собираем все через AND

Comment: Хотя с деревом и ИЛИ конечно то же собрать можно. Только процедуру надо сделать рекурсивной и при обнаружении вложенной структуре в дереве вызывать себя уже с этой веткой дерева, на выходе функция должна вернуть кусок условий в круглых скобках, что бы вышестоящая функция легко включила его в свою строку

Comment: Нормализовать, превратить в нормальную M:N схему. Фильтр хранить в виде построенного своим кодом (не введённого юзером!) SQL-текста WHERE-условия. Для выполнения использовать динамический SQL.

Comment: Уточню на всякий случай: глубина дерева представляющего фильтр может быть любой